# android starting services by name

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

My goal is to make 3 apks (for a very specific solution, not for normal consumption):

1. First contains the service, which starts at boot
2. A client that uses this service
3. Another client that uses this service

According to this site:
http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/06/start-service-at-boot/

I can to start a service just by knowing its name. However, this does not work:

```
// works
context.startService(new Intent(context, MyServiceMessenger.class));

// does not work
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent();
serviceIntent.setAction(MyService.SERVICE_CLASS_NAME);
context.startService(serviceIntent);
```

Needles to say the `MyService.SERVICE_CLASS_NAME`== `mypackage.MyServiceMessenger`.

My problem is on binding - where I need to bind to a service outside of my class.

```
// does not work
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyService.SERVICE_CLASS_NAME);

// works
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyServiceMessenger.class);

intent.putExtra("MESSENGER", messenger);        
context.bindService(intent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

When binding to the service by name, my `serviceConnection` is not been used at all, and I cannot send information to the service.

What am I missing?

Edit1:

I was missing an export in the manifest. You need to "export" it, and give it a name. I also gave permission to it. I am using the same string in my intent as the one  in @@ .

```
<permission android:name="MyPermission"
    android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.SYSTEM_TOOLS"
    android:protectionLevel="dangerous" />    
<uses-permission android:name="MyPermission" />    
<application ... >  
    <service
        android:name="service.MyServiceMessenger"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="MyPermission" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="**platinum8.service.P2PServiceMessenger**"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

</application>
```

EDIT 2:

I added an intent-filter with the same of the service name, and now my code seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly you are missing an `<intent-filter>` on your `<service>` element, where you declare the `<action>` you are trying to have the service respond to, such as:

```
<service android:name=".BshService">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.commonsware.android.advservice.IScript" />
  </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: @elcuco: `android:exported` is only needed if you do not have an `<intent-filter>`. Please add the `<intent-filter>` that matches your `Intent`.